# {React Native} Firing a function once State is up-to-date

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am struggling to figure out how to fire my `moveToResults()` function once the `setArr(list)` is filled. I feel like there should be a simple way to do this with a `new Promise`, but I cannot seem to figure it out.

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

const handlePress =  ()=>{
    var list = [];
    firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').where("location", "==" , place).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
                list.push(doc.data());                                                   
            })
             setArr(list);   
        }).then(()=>{
            console.log(arr.length);
        }).then(()=>{
            moveToResults(); // AT THIS POINT ARR.LENGTH IS STILL 0
        });
}
```

And this is my `moveToResults()` function:

```
    const moveToResults = () =>{ 
        navigation.navigate('Results', {arr: arr})
    }
```

**The question**

How do I make sure `moveToResults()`fires once `setArr(list)` is all the way done?

I basically want to make sure that when  `moveToResults()` is fired `arr` is populated. Otherwise I pass nothing to the next screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State updates are not reflected until a re-render actually happens. In class components, setState provides a callback which is called when the state update is complete, however in hook state updater there is no such callback provided

The way to handle such scenarios is to make use of useEffect and listen to the state change. However since you do not want this is to on initialRender, you need to disable the effect on initialRender

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
    if(!initialRender.current) {
        moveToResults()
    } else {
      initialRender.current = false;
    }

}, [arr]) // Listening on arr change


const handlePress =  ()=>{
    var list = [];
    firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').where("location", "==" , place).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
                list.push(doc.data());                                                   
            })
             setArr(list);   
        })
}
```

Howeve the above solution only works if the arr is being updated by handlePress action only or you want to navigate anytime there is a change in array. If the array is being updated from elsewhere and you do not wish to perform navigation on every array change, you cannot use the above approach

The correct way to handle such scenarios is to not rely on state update but pass on the argument to moveToResults directly

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

const handlePress =  ()=>{
    firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').where("location", "==" , place).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
        var list = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
                list.push(doc.data());                                                   
            })
            return list;   
        }).then((list)=>{
            moveToResults(list); 
        });
}

const moveToResults = (list) =>{ 
    navigation.navigate('Results', {arr: list})
}
```

By writing a function `moveToResults` to accept an argument, you can use it anywhere and rely on the passing the updated state instead of waiting for it to use the value from state.

Comment: Thank you! I will test this today and let you know.

Comment: I ran a console.log here: .then((list)=>{ 
           console.log(list)                                                                                                     
          moveToResults(list); 
        });                                                                                                                                        list is undefined and the moveToResults therefore passes nothing

Comment: I am more interested in the first solution that you gave, the issue there though is that I need a soft refresh in order for the moveToResults() function to be fired.

Comment: Promise chaining should work. However the first solution would also not need a soft refresh. Could you explain more on what you meant

Comment: Sorry, are you hoping to get more details on what I mean by soft refresh or something else?

Comment: Yes, I meant that promise chainging should work in the first place but also the first solution will not need any refresh. What do you mean by soft refresh here

Comment: What I mean by soft refresh is that I need to either save my code in VS code or scroll down for a refresh, in order to have it work

Comment: Saving a code to see the effect shouldn't be an issue right?

Comment: Well the code is already saved, I have to double save to make it populate

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213848/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-illlil).

Answer (score 1):

Set state using the array returned by `querySnapshot.docs`:

```js
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

// This callback will be called after 'arr' get elements.
React.useEffect(() => {
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    moveToResults(arr); // go!
  }
}, [arr]);

const handlePress = () => {
  firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').where("location", "==" , place).get()
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    console.log(querySnapshot.docs); // debug array

    setArr(querySnapshot.docs); // setting list

    // moveToResults(querySnapshot.docs); // go!
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help once again. When I try this I have a few issues. the var i remains undefined and without increment. When I make a var i = 0 and then increment it with each iteration, i increases but i === querySnapshot.length - 1 is never true therefore the code inside that if statement does not executes. I think this is due to the fact that querySnapshot.length  - 1 is NaN.

Comment: Uhh, I think that querySnapshot is an object instead array. Let me make some changes, one moment.

Comment: @IlllIl I edited the answer to add a way to set array, bypassing a need for a foreach. What you think? This works? If not, please tell if 'querySnapshot.docs' returns array.

Comment: Thank you so much honestly for taking the time.. So basically what is happening is this. moveToResults() gets fired, but arr remains empty. Also querySnapshot.docs does return array

Comment: @IlllIl That's ok! What if you pass 'querySnapshot.docs' as param in 'moveToResults'? You could get the array inside function. I edited the answer.

Comment: That look good, I get 4 elements in my array which is correct and they pass to the next screen. The only problem I am having now is that they do not render within my arr.map. Do you think there is a way to basically tell the compiler to wait to execute moveToResults() until the function before is completed? I was thinking there would be a way to do this using async / await.. basically using promises? The only reason why I am asking is because I have other stuff going to moveToResults() and I really need to pass arr as a parameter.

Comment: I think that Async/Await/Promisse won't help you here. You can callback 'setArr', using 'useEffect'. Basically, the useEffect will be called after 'arr' get elements successfully (after setArr, right?). Then, you can 'moveToResults'! I edited the answer. Please, try.

Comment: moveToResults it's not firing. Dude, I voted you up for all the help, I'll have to figure something out.. not too sure at this point and I feel bad for taking so much of your time. Thanks a ton

Comment: So, setArr is not firing =(. I really idk why. No problem bro! Thanks for requesting help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213217/discussion-between-illlil-and-maycon-mesquita).

Comment: If you have any ideas since I notice you are pretty familiar with React-Native :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61630313/react-native-await-not-blocking-execution

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use redux, that would help a lot in this situation?

Anyway I was thinking, something like this:

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

    const handlePress = () => {
       firebase.firestore()
               .collection('PostedFunEvents')
               .where("location", "==" , place)
               .get()
               .then(snapshot => {

        let list = [];

        if (snapshot.empty) {
          throw new Error('No location here.');
        }  

        snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          list.push(doc);
        });

        if (snapshot.length === list.length) {
          setArr(list)
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
         console.log('Error getting documents', err);
      });
}
```

I hope it helps, or at least that it works

Comment: Grazie Marco! Italiano FTW. Anyway English only here i guess. Thanks so much for taking a shot at this.. I will definitely test this out, follow up question to what you shared.. where would you suggest I should fire moveToResults() ?

Comment: Where did I use italian? :O

Comment: Anyway, I was thinking , you could use sorry, i totally forgot the part, of moveToResult, i'll comment once more with a pastebin to add that

Comment: No you did not comment in Italian I did. I was about to comment back in Italian since I noticed you are Italian also, but then I was like "nah.. English only here" Anyway, thanks, I'll waiting for the new comment

Comment: Here it is: https://pastebin.com/PGV8fVb9, if it doesn't help I could help you tell me

Comment: @IlllIl Did that help solving the problem?

Comment: It did not, unfortunately moveToResults() never gets fired

Comment: What do you see if you console log snapshot? And also what type of object is that

Comment: I get a long arr with string objects. I can see the correct values that are stored in my firestore, my API and a bunch of other information

Comment: Did you also track with a console log how list is filled?  The lenght of the snapshot, if setArr is called? I'm sorry it didn't help , anyway maybe tracking all the dataflow will solve your problem, if still that doesn't help try adding redux, as I said before it helps a lot design a dataflow structure

Comment: Ok thanks alot dude, I am not crazy familiar with Redux, do you have any good sources for me to read about? I will try to log a few more things later today.

Comment: Well first the docs , they're written in a really good way. Maybe I can show you my code in a react native project I'm making for a university exam,

Comment: That would be awesome.I am doing the same here, working on my university exam.

Comment: Look me up on facebook, I'll try to help you ( before publicly showing the repo I have to change a lot of things , tomorrow I'll probably be ready to do it )

Comment: Anyway, could you upvote me at least for the effort :D

Comment: I do not have facebook, but we could chat over StackOverflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213310/discussion-between-illlil-and-marco-edoardo-duma).

Answer (score 0):

instead of using multiple `.then()` blocks, you can use async await in your firebase operation completion, i.e

```
firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').where("location", "==" , place).get().then(async (querySnapshot) =>{
 await querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
            list.push(doc.data());                                                   
        })
         setArr(list);   
    })
 .catch(err=>{
console.log(err)
 })
```

Comment: On ` await querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>` I get this message **await has not effect on the type of this expression.**

Comment: This is it: **const [arr, setArr] = useState([])**; I am basically just setting the state of arr

Answer (score 0):

The `arr` variable will not get populated until your component re-renders, therefore you cannot call `moveToResults` in the same promise chain.  However, this should be a simple check when the `arr` is populated and then call the function.

```
const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
  if (arr.length > 0) {
    moveToResults(arr);
  }
}, [arr])

const handlePress =  ()=>{
    var list = [];
    firebase.firestore().collection('PostedFunEvents').where("location", "==" , place).get().then((querySnapshot) =>{
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) =>{ 
                list.push(doc.data());                                                   
            })
             // Use concat because it returns a new array which will allow react to detect a state change
            setArr(arr.concat(list));   
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can write customise function which will call the callBack function if any changes in the state

then you can fire function from callback

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const useStateCallbackWrapper = (initilValue, callBack) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initilValue);
  useEffect(() => callBack(state), [state]);
  return [state, setState];
};

const callBack = state => {
  console.log("---------------", state);
};
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useStateCallbackWrapper(0, callBack);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this dude. setArr and navigation should be called only after the list is available.

```
const handlePress = async () => {

  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const list = [];
    firebase
        .firestore()
        .collection('PostedFunEvents')
        .where("location", "==", place)
        .get()
        .then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach(doc =>
              list.push(doc.data()
              ));
          resolve(list);
        }).catch(reject);
  });

  try {
    const myList = await myPromise();
    console.log(myList);
    setArr(list);
    navigation.navigate('Results', {arr: myList});
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will test this out as soon as possible and I will get back to you